# Google Search Result Encoding in Chinese

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, google-search, rcurl

all

I've been working on the **R** program for google search data mining.
So far, my codes run well, except for the Traditional Chinese encoding problem.
I'm working under the linux environment...

```
Google <- function(input)
  {
   require(XML)
   require(stringr)
   require(RCurl)
   hits <- GoogleHits(input)
   if( hits >= 1000){
      start.num = seq(0,900,100) 
  }else if(hits < 1000){
      start.num = seq(0,hits,100) 
  }
  for(i in 1:length(start.num)){
       start = start.num[i] 
       url <-paste("https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=",input,
       "&as_occt=title&num=100&ie=UTF-8&start=",start, sep = "")   


   CAINFO = paste(system.file(package="RCurl"), "/CurlSSL/ca-bundle.crt", sep = "")
   script <- getURL(url, followlocation = TRUE, cainfo = CAINFO)

   # using htmlParse() to re-organize the whole structure
   # the Chinese encoding shows quite well here 
   # (but the structure is not a vector)     
   doc <- htmlParse(script)

   # Wanna extract out the searched keyword
   # which is tagged by "<b>keyword</b>"
   # here, I take the keyword "統計" for example
   extract <- str_extract_all(html_str, "<b>統計</b>")

   # here is the problem... which extract only takes a vector as an argument
   # so below will return an error
   print (extract)

}
  }
```

So, the problems that I encountered are all included in the comments.

1) if not using **htmlParse()**, the extracted data can not be presented into recognized Chinese characters

2) if I've tried to convert the data into a vector (by applying **script <- lapply(url, getURL)**), though the **str_extract_all()** method can be used, the encoding problem arises...

In addition, the Chinese here I meant is the **Traditional Chinese**

Any comments or suggestions are truly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is GoogleHits() defined?

Answer (score 2):

I found the bug! Myself!
So I am here to answer the question.

The problem is the parameter in the given **url link**!

Since the encoding of the Chinese is UTF-8,
there are two parameters that are necessarily needed,
**oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8** !!
(which in the google's developers website,
it says that the **oe=UTF-8** do not need to be specified,
and that's why I've skipped the part...)

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Congratulations for finding the bug! Yourself!